# Custom D3 `tickValue` on x axis -- horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to create custom tick values on X axis.

Chart is generated from data.csv file. There are 144 data points. Each data value represent 10 minutes cycle, so first tick should appear on 6th tick representing 1 hour.

If I use `.domain([new Date('2014-03-08T12:00:00'), new Date('2014-03-9T00:00:00')])` for example, I will get X axis right, but my chart would be gone.

I can't use `tickValues([])` in this case either.

What I should see on X axis is something like this `00:00 AM...(6 tick values)...1:00 AM...(6 tick values)...2:00 AM` etc. Or it could be `00:00 AM...(12 tick values)...2:00 AM...(12 tick values)...3:00 AM` etc. Just to be able to customize it.

Not sure if this is even possible. I tried following this simple example http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3059392, but again, I get X axis right, but my chart is gone.

This would be the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/kc4E43Bgo4bNMB9hKX2j?p=preview

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm confused. What ticks exactly do you want? Your data doesn't seem to contain dates at all.

Comment: My data doesn't contain dates, no. I want to have custom tick values that aren't fed from csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data **doesn't contain** actual date values, this is my solution:

You want to show one tick out of 6, since each tick represents 10 minutes and you want to show only the "hourly" tick. So, define the tick values using your x scale domain:

```
.tickValues(d3.range(x.domain()[0], x.domain()[1]).filter(function(d) {
    return d % 6 === 0;
}))
```

And then, format the ticks to add a `:00` to each one:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d/6 + ":00";
});
```

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8EOGt8UvYq1J8qpIdArN?p=preview

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, here is the solution with "am" and "pm": https://plnkr.co/edit/OvtVlgT4I6Y19hgoMKIK?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Mr. Furtado! You have been very helpful again! I see exactly what you did with `.range` and `.filter`, but it still doesn't look quite intuitive. If I see number 18:00 for example, it is still confusing to realize that is actually 3 hours. I will see if I can get json  for this with dates. But than I need completely new chart. I understand that this is the closest I can get... If you say so, it must be it since I don't have actual date values. Thank you once again!

Comment: You can loop into a 24-hour ticks (I can show you how to do it later, I'm on my mobile now), even with am and pm, but be advised that this would be a **totally fake** axis.

Comment: No rush! Thank you so much! I'm aware that this will be a fake axis. And that is ok! What is represented on the chart is coming from csv, and that is the most important. There are 144 data values for 24 hours with 10 minutes interval. Thank you!!!

Comment: It always starts at 12am (midnight), is that correct?

Comment: OK. I'll edit my answer later, with another solution. Cheers.

Comment: Wow! This is it! That is exactly what I was trying to get. I voted both of your answers! THANK you so much!!!

Comment: I'm just going over your code again. Adding conditional statement like that was so clever. I have to add that. Thanks again! Cheers!